polars "ModuleNotFoundError: pyarrow>=8.0.0 is required for `to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)`". How can I solve this?
I am doing a project for my thesis, and I have to analyze a fairly big dataset, around 260k rows per 13 columns after removing the NaNs and NULLs. I have done a good bunch of it with pandas, but I recently learned about polars and I wanted to try to use it in my project.
I am encountering issues involving pyarrow (already installed) This is the code snippet, I will cut the markdown cells for simplicity:
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Loading the dataset:
combined_dataframe_polars = pl.read_csv("../../DATA/FINAL/dataframe_cleaned.csv")
# Removed meaningless stuff for the question
# ========================= it executes flawlessly until here ========================= #

# Converting from pl to pd:
combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe_polars.to_pandas(
    use_pyarrow_extension_array=True
)

The error I get is this:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13984\2858077455.py in ?()
      1 # Converting from pl to pd:
----> 2 combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe_polars.to_pandas(
      3     use_pyarrow_extension_array=True
      4 )
      5 

c:\Users\Marco\anaconda3\envs\machinelearning\Lib\site-packages\polars\dataframe\frame.py in ?(self, use_pyarrow_extension_array, **kwargs)
   2385                 if _PYARROW_AVAILABLE:
   2386                     msg += f", found pyarrow {pa.__version__!r}."
   2387                     raise ModuleUpgradeRequiredError(msg)
   2388                 else:
-> 2389                     raise ModuleNotFoundError(msg)
   2390 
   2391         # Object columns must be handled separately as Arrow does not convert them
   2392         # correctly

ModuleNotFoundError: pyarrow>=8.0.0 is required for `to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)`

On a side note, I already tried this version of the cell:
# Converting from pl to pd:
combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe_polars.to_pandas()

I tried executing the bunch, which executed without issues when I used just pandas, but I get this pyarrow related error.
I was expecting to simply convert the dataframe between polars and pandas, but evidently something isn't right.
The question is: how can I solve this issue and convert the dataframe successfully? Should I go back to using just pandas for simplicity?
NOTE: pyarrow is installed, version 16.1.0.

have you tried restarting your notebook and running it all again?

Could you please run pl.show_versions() before [...].to_pandas(...)? What does it display?

@Hericks I have already run it in review phase and indeed it shows that pyarrow version is the one in the post, 16.1.0.

@ignoring_gravity yes, multiple times.

Could you uninstall polars in the env (verify that the import no longer works), then re-install using pip install polars[pandas,pyarrow] (does not need to be pip)?
